# I loaded package broom but still could not find function tidy; help appreciated

Tags: r, dataframe, summary, tidy

> tidy (ad_aov)
> Error in tidy(ad_aov) : could not find function "tidy"

Comment: when you say have loaded, did you do `library(broom)`

Answer (score 0):

You can run this code:

```
library(broom)
broom::tidy(ad_aov)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot;
I explain what hapenned and the solution;

My problem was that the function tidy, included in broom, was not recognized by R studio as I expected.

I had installed the tidyberse package in RStudio and then I loaded is as well into the library and I assummed that because broom is in the tidyverse package it would be loaded to the library.
I found out in the help, that when you load tidyverse into the library it only loads some of the subpackages of tidyverse, and broom is not included; you have to load it separately.
I did, and it worked, i.e., RStudio found and implemented the broom function.
I hope this helps anyone in the same situation